# Alternative Efficient approach to pandas where

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to use pandas `pd.DataFrame.where` as follows:

```
df.where(cond=mask, other=df.applymap(f))
```

Where `f` is a user defined function to operate on a single cell. I cannot use `other=f` as it seems to produce a different result.

So basically I want to evaluate the function `f` at all cells of the DataFrame which does not satisfy some condition which I am given as the `mask`.

The above usage using `where` is not very efficient as it evaluates `f` immediately for the entire DataFrame `df`, whereas I only need to evaluate it at some entries of the DataFrame, which can sometimes be very few specific entries compared to the entire DataFrame.

Is there an alternative usage/approach that could be more efficient in solving this general case?

Comment: Can you pls provide sample data and function definition?

Comment: Can't you modify f? If not, `df.applymap(lambda x: f(x) if cond else x)` should do it without needing where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you correctly stated, `df.applymap(f)` is evaluated before `df.where()`. I'm fairly certain that `df.where()` is a quick function and is not the bottleneck here.

It's more likely that `df.applymap(f)` is inefficient, and there's usually a faster way of doing `f` in a vectorized manner. Having said so, if you do believe this is impossible, and `f` is itself slow, you could modify `f` to leave the input unchanged wherever your mask is `False`. This is most likely going to be really slow though, and you'll definitely prefer trying to vectorize f instead.

If you really must do it element-wise, you could use a NumPy array:

```
result = df.values
for (i,j) in np.where(mask):
    result[i,j] = f(result[i,j])
```

It's critical that you use a NumPy array for this, rather than `.iloc` or `.loc` in the dataframe, because indexing a pandas dataframe is slow.

You could compare the speed of this with `.applymap`; for the same operation, I don't think `.applymap` is substantially faster (if at all) than simply a for loop, because all pandas does is run a for loop of its own in Python (maybe Cython? But even that only saves on the overhead, and not the function itself). This is different from 'proper' vectorization, because vector operations are implemented in C.

Comment: `you could modify f to leave the input unchanged wherever your mask is False` is exactly what I am looking for. How would you achieve this?

Comment: I actually made that statement under the assumption that your boolean mask only depends on the values of your data, which is probably not the case. If it indeed isn't, then it's impossible to do without some ridiculous use of global variables. This is because `.applymap` only passes the value (and not the index) into `f`.